# Retrieve and update specific row data in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve data from a data table and beside each retrieved row there will be an update button and with update button click it will update only that specific row only. For this I have tried following code but it is updating all data records in a single click. How can I update particular row only?

```
<?php                    
  global $wpdb;
  $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_share" );
  echo '<table border=1 class="table table-striped">
  <tr><th>Id</th><th>purchasedate</th><th>purchasevalue</th>
  <th>offervalue</th><th>monthlyearnings</th><th>status</th></tr>';

        foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){
        echo '<tr><td>'. $retrieved_data->id.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$retrieved_data->purchasedate.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$retrieved_data->purchasevalue.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $retrieved_data->offervalue.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $retrieved_data->monthlyearnings.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $retrieved_data->status.'</td>';
   ?>
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <td><input type="submit"  name="update" value="update"  /></td>
    </form>
  <?php 
     $myid= $retrieved_data->id;

     if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    //global $wpdb;
     ?><script>//alert('<?php// echo $myid; ?>');</script><?php
     $wpdb->update('wp_share', array( 'Status' => 'pay'),array('id'=>$myid));

     }
    }?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below code.

```
     <?php global $wpdb;
  $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts" );
  echo '<table border=1 class="table table-striped">
  <tr><th>Id</th><th>purchasedate</th><th>purchasevalue</th>
  <th>offervalue</th> <th>status</th></tr>';

        foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){

        echo '<tr><td>'. $retrieved_data->ID.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$retrieved_data->post_author.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$retrieved_data->post_date.'</td>';

        echo '<td>'. $retrieved_data->post_title.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $retrieved_data->comment_status.'</td>';
   ?>
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <td>
     <input type="hidden" name="pid" value= "<?php echo $retrieved_data->ID; ?>">
     <input type="submit"  name="update" value="update"  /></td>
    </form>
  <?php 


     if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
      $myid = $_POST['pid'];
      global $wpdb;
     ?> <?php
     $wpdb->update('wp_posts', array( 'comment_status' => 'pay'),array('id'=>$myid));

     }
    }?>
```